# Archer - archer data feed

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I am new to RSA archer. Appologies if this is a basic question but I and wanted to understand what is archer-archer data feed.  And how we can accomplish  it in archer?

Answer (score 2):

An Archer-to-Archer data feed provides the ability to pull data from an instance in the form of an XML query or report-based search. The source data is inserted in its raw or formatted state either:

back into the same application,

a different application,

or even a different instance entirely.

**For example**, lets say you want to insert data from application Contacts and update a few fields of Contacts (lets say, Name and Email) into another application User Details. 
Lets say you have fields UserName and UserEmail in Users application. You want to copy data from:

**'Name' at Contacts to 'UserName' in User Details, and**

**'Email' at Contacts to 'UserEmail' in User Details**

Here what you do is, build a global report containing a key field of Contacts application, 'Name' field and 'Email' field. This report acts as a source for your data-feed. Now, in an A2A data-feed, map these source fields from the source report to target application fields in the data-feed. Define the key field in your mapping. Now, run the data-feed. The data will be copied across the applications.

Hope this gives you an idea!

Look, data-feed is a vast concept and you will require to dig-in deep for a complete understanding and know what all possibilities and limitations exist therein. I would suggest you to read the admin guide also for that.

Also, Thanks for making the RSA Archer community grow on stackoverflow.